# converting a SPA from elm to an android app

Tags: javascript, android, single-page-application, elm

I understand that elm compiles down to JS - can the resultant .js file then be easily converted to an android app using existing tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elm Native UI](https://github.com/ohanhi/elm-native-ui) is a project that is being worked on, which builds on top of Facebook's React Native, but it's not production ready yet.

Comment: can the .js file be converted directly using React Native?

Comment: It can not. If you're using Elm Native UI, you need to create a special program using the `NativeUI.program` instead of `Html.program`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Android, but I'm pretty sure you could create a working application with Elm and embed it into an Android app using a [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). It's not going to be as performant as a native application, but it will work for simpler apps.